# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Tags: spacy, modulenotfounderror

[spacy showing module not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSBn3.png)

tried installation many types

```
- python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
- conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Tried these two but not working So tell me what to do, guys Android running it several times. I also updated pip the But then nothing is working.

Comment: What is your python version?